# window.open on a-tag for new tab

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, window.open

I am using this code to open a new tab:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('https://example.com','_blank')">linktext</a>
```

The new page is also loaded within a new tab however at the source page it is shown `[object]`instead of the link. What is wrong?

I do not want to use

```
<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank")">linktext</a>
```

because I generate a list of links and the target page is called differently for each link. The most flexible way for me is to use the give Syntax.

EDIT:
This is the generated linklist:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('https://example.com','_blank')">linktext 1</a>
<a href="javascript:jsfunc1(param1)">linktext 2</a>
<a href="javascript:jsfunc2(param2,param3)">linktext 3</a>
```

The href attribute is generated. I get a from a table.

Comment: The example at the top works just fine; [proof](https://jsfiddle.net/mkmxyueu/). We can't help you without an example of what *isn't* working.

Comment: where do you see [object]? your question is completely unclear. Are you populating the url in the href looping an array? show the code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think OP is sending the url to the href from an array and the script is placing Object instead of the expected value from the array. We miss the whole necessary code

Comment: you see the generated code. When clicking on the first link the target page is loaded correctly, but on the source page (where I come from) I see the text [object] instead of the linklist. In the jsfiddle by @T.J.Crowder the effect is also visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of a `javascript:` scheme URL is to *generate a replacement page from JavaScript*. It isn't designed to run JavaScript in response to a client while leaving the page alone — that is what event handlers are for.

The new "page" you are seeing is the result of converting the reference to the new window to a string.

This is best avoided by not using JavaScript for this:

```
<a href="https://example.com" target='_blank'>linktext</a>
```

You can also do it by avoiding using `javascript:` scheme URIs and binding your JS separately (with a sensible fallback in the href):

```
<a href="https://example.com">linktext</a>

<script>
    document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", your_function);
    function your_function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        // Then do whatever else you want the function to do
    }
</script>
```

If you really want to use the JavaScript URL scheme (which, as I suggested above, is a dirty hack), you can ensure that the script returns nothing using the `void` operator:

```
<a href="javascript:void (window.open('https://example.com','_blank'))">linktext</a>
```

Comment: You are the only one who read my question carefully and pointed out how to avoid the current behaviour. Thanks to you!

Answer (score -1):

The Above Example Works Well. Checkout Below Code :

```html
<a href="javascript:window.open('https://example.com','_blank')">linktext</a>
```

Other Ways To Open Link in New Tab :

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', '_blank')">test</a>
```

Without JS :

```
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">test</a>
```

Comment: "The Above Example Works Well" — Not being able to reproduce the problem isn't something that should go in an answer.